# Mean and Standard Deviation of Columns Using Default Functions

Tags: python, function, default

The problem is asking to make a function to find the mean and standard deviation of the given excel file. The twist is that the last column of each row represents whether if the row is a '0' row or a '1' row. We need to find a function that you can input on many columns you want to test and if you want to test the '0's and/or the '1's. Here's my current code:

```
def mean(column, one, zero):
    for item in data:
        if item in data:
            item[[8]] = 0
        elif item in data:
            item[[8]] = 1
        sum = sum(item[[column]])
    return sum / len(item[[column]])
print(mean(1))

def standard_deviation(column, one, zero):
    for item in data:
        if item in data:
            item[[8]] = 0
        elif item in data:
            item[[8]] = 1
    mean = mean(column)
    temp = 0
    for item in data:
        temp = temp + ((item - mean) ** 2)
    return (temp / len(column)) ** 0.5
```

And the data that was given to us:

```
[['1', '85', '66', '29', '0', '26.6', '0.351', '31', '0'], ['8', '183', '64', '0', '0', '23.3', '0.672', '32', '1'], ['1', '89', '66', '23', '94', '28.1', '0.167', '21', '0'], ['0', '137', '40', '35', '168', '43.1', '2.288', '33', '1'], ['5', '116', '74', '0', '0', '25.6', '0.201', '30', '0'], ['3', '78', '50', '32', '88', '31.0', '0.248', '26', '1'], ['10', '115', '0', '0', '0', '35.3', '0.134', '29', '0'], ...
```

and so forth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please tell us what `one` and `zero` are  supposed to be? They're unused in your current functions. And what are you trying to achieve with the notation `item[[column]]` which is not a valid operation on Python lists.

Comment: They're supposed to be for the user when they use the function and note if they want to include only the 'one' rows and or the 'zero's. I'm sorry for my bad coding, I'm not great at Python.

Comment: You don't have to apologise for not knowing something, especially not on a site like this that is meant to help people! I just want to know exactly what you need your code to do so I know how to answer your question, and the more details you can give us, the better.

Comment: The user is supposed to be able to use the 'mean' and 'stand_deviation' functions by simply entering how many columns they want. If the user only inputs the columns, then it should print the mean of the columns provided. If the user provides if the function is 'zero' then it will show the mean of the rows with only 'zero' and vise versa with the 'one'. The professor worded it quite weirdly.

Comment: Professors question: write one function that calculates BOTH the mean and SD (return both values), your function should be named something like calculateMeanSD and takes four arguments.  The first argument should be the set of data, the second argument the number of the column you are calculating for and the third and fourth argument should be optional indicating the feature number of the last column and what value you are restricting to.

Comment: It's not clear to me what a "feature number" is, sadly. If you have a syllabus or something, try looking it up in there.

Comment: It's also not clear to me if you need to calculate the mean and SD for a single column or all columns up to a specific one.

Comment: The example he provided was this: For Feature 8=1, Feature 0: mean = 4.87  sd = 3.74
For Feature 8=1, Feature 1: mean = 1.41e+02  sd = 31.9
For Feature 8=1, Feature 2: mean = 70.8  sd = 21.5
For Feature 8=1, Feature 3: mean = 22.2  sd = 17.7
For Feature 8=1, Feature 4: mean = 1e+02  sd = 1.39e+02
For Feature 8=1, Feature 5: mean = 35.1  sd = 7.26
For Feature 8=1, Feature 6: mean = 0.55  sd = 0.372
For Feature 8=1, Feature 7: mean = 37.1  sd = 11.0

Comment: He also stated: Each column is a feature value describing a data point.  The nine columns describe one data instance.  The last column is the "class" feature, whether or not the row is an example of the concept (value is 1) or not an example of the concept.  Write a program that calculates the mean and standard deviation of each feature column.  Then, repeat the calculation for the case where the last column is 0 and then where the last column is 1.

Comment: a bit confusing for an introduction class

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what the intent is. You may want to ask your professor directly.

Comment: The intent is to find the mean and standard deviation for all of the columns individually and be able to separate them by the last or 8th column whether the number is '1' or '0'. The 'feature' just simply means what column each is. Lastly my intended purpose of the  item[[column]] was so the user could enter an amount of columns and the program would find the mean of that many columns. For instance, item[[column=3]] would find the mean/std of column 1, column 2, and column 3.